I tried Ubuntu via USB once. Why can't I boot back into Windows anymore?
Recently I tried getting my PC to dual boot between Windows 11 and Ubuntu, however something happened. I booted from the Ubuntu USB, my PC hung on its corresponding loading screen (after making it past the livecd menu), and I subsequently shut it off. I then tried booting back into Windows as normal, but instead my PC hangs on the loading screen. I tried getting back into the Ubuntu USB and that can load with no issues.
I tried creating a Windows 11 USB to see if I could repair my installation. However even that doesn't boot properly; I just reach a deep purple screen with nothing to interact with.
I'm not sure what's going on or why trying Ubuntu only once would have such a huge effect on my PC. I can't load back into Windows at all, and I don't wanna install Ubuntu if I can't access Windows. Does anyone have ideas of what I can investigate first?

Which version of Ubuntu did you try?

I tried 22.04 LTS

Does this answer your question? Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?

I'm not sure if this helps, as I didn't even install Ubuntu. I still have yet to install it. Are you suggesting I install it?

You should always be able to boot Windows via the UEFI menu (some key at power up, select Windows from the menu).

I think in my case it might be F8 that brings up a menu of all bootable mediums. I have booted Windows from this menu and I still had the issue of it hanging on the loading screen.

I have never heard of or faced this problem of just booting from Ubuntu USB messing up Windows boot process. I think Windows got corrupted due to another reason, possibly a bad update or corrupted internal drive.

I'm not sure of what other details I can share. I have no reason to suspect a bad update or corrupted drive because prior to this on the same day everything worked just fine when it came to booting into Windows. I'm simply describing what happened, unless there's a hidden detail I don't know about to look for? Could it be a bios thing?

Does this answer your question? How to change boot priority?
